# Calling a method trough prototype vs calling it directly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between `Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')` and `arguments.join('')` and why would one use one over the other? I keep seeing the first method being used more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is based on a false premise.

You *cannot* use `arguments.join('')`, because `arguments` does not have such a method. The `arguments` object has similarities to an array (e.g. integer properties, `length` property), but it's not actually an array. However, those similarities are enough to enable the use of the array prototype's `join` method on it.

Answer (score 1):

`arguments.join` does not exist, so there is a clear difference. `arguments` is not an array, but it behaves like an array (has numeric properties and a length), so it is possible to use the array method on it manually by using `Array.prototype.join.call`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mistake arguments for an array, it is array-like but doesn't have all the methods or properties an array object usually would. For example, join does not exist in the arguments object, thus you cannot call arguments.join(). But we know join exists in Array.prototype, so we can call this and pass the arguments object as the calling instance along with the join parameters, like so :

```
Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')
```

This means calling join method in Array.prototype but use the arguments as the object instance or else known as "this" for the join method invocation. So you see even though the method is not present in the arguments object, we are making the illusion that it is buy invoking the call method. This technique is great to be used in such cases. Note: arguments can actually act as the "this" or instance in this case is because it has centain property names identical to any ordinary Array object and thus will handle properly a join innocation. Hope that help!! :)